# php form not inserting to sql database

Tags: php, html, sql, mysqli

I am attempting to get into php and mysql, i have created this form for inserting data to my database, however upon filling in the form, no data gets inserted into the sql database. the information is to be inserted into a table with multiple foreignkeys. When debugging the sql i get the error message:bad query:INSERT INTO bud('beløp,idkjoper,idgjenstand') VALUES ('7500','3','1') which are the correct values.

I suspect the issue is that i am attempting to have a list with the buyers name, and then register the bid the buyerID for the bid. I am trying to get around having to remember the buyerID to make a bid, but instead have the buyers name appear in a list, and upon selecting the buyers name, getting the buyers ID inserted into the database.

If you could take minute of your day to take a look, i would greatly appreciate it:)
Here is the sql segment.

```
<?php
$tilkobling=mysqli_connect ("localhost","root","root", "bruktbutikk");
$sql="select navn,etternavn from kjøper";
$datasett = $tilkobling->query($sql);


  $conn=mysqli_connect ("localhost","root","root", "bruktbutikk");
  $sql1="select beskrivelse,idgjenstand from gjenstand";
  $datasett1=$conn->query($sql1);

   if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
  {
   $sql =sprintf("INSERT INTO bud(beløp,idkjoper,idgjenstand) VALUES 
   (%s,%s,%s)",

             $tilkobling->real_escape_string($_POST["lstnavn"]),
             $tilkobling->real_escape_string($_POST["lstbeskrivelse"]),
             $tilkobling->real_escape_string($_POST["txtbeløp"])


     );

     $tilkobling->query($sql);

header("Location: budok.php");
  }

   ?>
```

here is my form:

```
     <main>
        <h1> Gi bud</h1>
<br/>

<form method="post">

    <label for="lstnavn">Budgiver:</label>
    <select name="lstnavn" id="lstnavn">
     <?php while($rad=mysqli_fetch_array($datasett)) { ?>
     <option value="<?php echo $rad["idkjoper"]; ?>"> 
      <?php echo $rad["navn"], ($rad['etternavn']); ?>
         </option>}
        <br><br>
     <?php } ?> <br><br>
     </select>

    <br>

    <form method="post">
    <div>
    <label for="lstbeskrivelse">gjenstand:</label>
    <select name="lstbeskrivelse" id="lstbeskrivelse">
     <?php while($rad=mysqli_fetch_array($datasett1)) { ?>
         <option value="<?php echo $rad["idgjenstand"]; ?>"> <?php echo 
      $rad["beskrivelse"]; ?>
         </option>}
        <br><br>
     <?php } ?> <br><br>
     </select>

    <br>

     <label for="txtbeløp">beløp:</label>
    <input type="text" name="txtbeløp" id="txtbeløp" 
      placeholder="beløp" /> <br/><br>





    <br/>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Publiser</button>
    </form>


   </main>
```

Comment: Your INSERT shouldn't have the WHERE clause

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i removed the where clause on my insert statement, but unfortunatly it did not fix the issue. @NigelRen

Comment: **Notice** You should know that, there is no anything called PHP form. It is called HTML form. PHP has no forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your errors:

1. Your query contains 3 column-names, your values-part 4 `%s`
2. `real_escape_string()` doesn't add quotes to a string, use `".. VALUES('%s', '%s', '%s')"` or have a look at prepared statements

How to debug:

`$tilkobling->query()` returns false on failure, use `var_dump($tilkobling->error)` to display the error-message when that is the case, and of course a `var_dump($sql)` to see what is realy send to MySQL.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Thank you for your reply , i changed the values to be 3 %s and changed added var_dump($tilkobling->error) i recieved this message: string(153) "bad query:INSERT INTO bud('beløp,idkjoper,idgjenstand') VALUES ('7500','3','1')" @petervanderwal –

Comment: `bud('beløp,idkjoper,idgjenstand')` < Those quotes shouldn't be there